# jQuery ui tabs issue

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, tabs

I came back to a problem we never found an answer to regarding the homepage of a site I am working on and I said that my tabs would just scatter on a resolution less than mine or around it but not quite. I am on a 1280x800 screen and it displays no problem but as soon as I drop to 1024x768 or 1280x1024 or anything like that this is what it looks like.

I wanted to post the code but it means posting a lot of HTML and I don't think that will be healthy. Hopefully the screenshot will do. Someone said a while back that my tabs were too big so I reduced them and still. Here is the screenshot though:

[warpped homepage screenshot http://www.thelawyerschronicle.com/upload_pics/Screenshot.png](http://www.thelawyerschronicle.com/upload_pics/Screenshot.png)

Here is the CSS that powers the adverts. The CSS for the rest of the site is just a normal jQuery UI base.

```
#adverts{
    padding:0px;
    width:400px;
    height:109px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left:320px;
/*  margin-right: auto; */
}
```

Comment: to get proper help on this make a new html page that is simple so you can post the html and I assure you that will help you find the problem quickly or allow us to answer properly

Comment: ok thanks for the tip. i'll try that and post up quickly

Comment: hey bobby like i suspected the code is simply too long for me to post. maybe I will post a new post with just he code

Comment: no sorry the css code that powers the header completely. that is what I meant and sorry for calling you by first name. don't even know what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

Whatever region the tabs are being written to is having its width constrained, causing the premature wrap to the next line (I assume this is the problem you're having-- your question is not explicit on what the problem is).  I'd fish around with Firebug until whatever sized div or margin is causing the space to be limited.